# KVM switch switches automatically on VirtualBox usage

Tags: virtualbox, kvm-switch

I am using KVM switch Multico EW K1904U. The problem is that it confilcts with Oracle virtual box somehow.

Particularly, if I am terminating virtual machine on computer 1, it switches to computer 2 (computer 1 and computer 2 are physical computer and computer 2 is never used in the case).

Comment: Your KVM switch probably detects an ACPI event. Are there any configurable safeguarding mechanism in that switch?